# Vuex vs Simple Shared Data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

Is there anything Vuex can do that the following simple shared store can not? --

```
let store = {
    user: {
        name: 'John Doe'
    }
};

new Vue({
    el: '#app-one',
    data: {
        bar: 'foo',
        shared: store
    }
 });

new Vue({
    el: '#app-two',
    data: {
        foo: 'bar',
        shared: store
    }
 });
```

If so, what are those common use cases?

Comment: Yeah, I still don't get it. How is Vuex different than a "global" object with maybe some methods that enforce what you need. The Vuex documentation advises using this approach until you know you'll need Vuex (it's like glasses, you'll know when you need it).  I still am not at that point. I haven't seen anything a simple global object didn't solve for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Deep down, a Vuex store is just a Vue reactive object as the one you are adding.

So if you would only use the `state` of the Vuex store via **direct access**, then the two approaches work the same.

The thing is, if, in Vuex, you are using only the `state` directly, you are pretty much underusing the tool. You are paying the price, but not reaping the benefits.

Vuex has getters, which are like reusable computed properties. They also allow you to decouple your apps from the inner structure of the store's state.

Vuex has modules/namespaces, which allow you to break down your store code and better organize it as it grows.

Vuex also have actions and mutations. Actions allow you to create "methods" that are reusable by any Vue instance (or component) that uses the store. Another important thing is actions and mutations enforce a "protocol" that will also help you to better organize your code and, most importantly of all: will help you **debug** your code more easily when things get troublesome (and they will, if your app grows enough).

For one example, consider an app which many points of the app change the same bit of state. Consider also that some of these changes are done asynchronously. Using Vuex, you know that any async  operation is being done within actions, so if you have any "race" problem, the source of the issue must be there. In Vuex, you also know that, ultimately, the changes to the state are made at mutations **only** (and synchronously). So if things get crazy, you can always place a breakpoint at that mutation and find out what the heck is invoking it. If you don't use Vuex, in any reasonably big app, the changes will come from too many places at too many rates, making your life not so easy after all.